# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I would like to read out data from excel sheet using xlrd. I want to go through specific cells from the excel and if I didn't find the number "1" I want to add +1 to the row number and start again. My problem is that when I specify the cell in the for loop I get a TypeError:'int' object is not subscriptable.

```
import xlrd

Excelsheet1 = "info_2020.xlsx" 
Book1 = xlrd.open_workbook(Excelsheet1) 
first_sheet = Book1.sheet_by_index(9)

row_num = 1

for look_for_one in first_sheet.row_values(row_num[12]):
        if look_for_one == 1:
            print(first_sheet.row_values(row_num)[25])
        else:
            row_num += 1
```

Anyone knows what is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you forgot a parenthesis and wrote `first_sheet.row_values(row_num[12])` instead of `first_sheet.row_values(row_num)[12]`. Thus the error message is "`int is not subscriptable`" which means "I don't understand `row_num[12]` because `row_num` is an int (a number), not a list."

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if error message shows you in which line is problem then use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: Thank you Stef, you are right. Now it's working!

Comment: @Stef For me, that would be a valid answer to be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot a parenthesis and wrote `first_sheet.row_values(row_num[12])` instead of `first_sheet.row_values(row_num)[12]`.

Thus the error message is "`int is not subscriptable`" which means "I don't understand `row_num[12]` because row_num is an int (a number), not a list."